# Search for several arguments with Doctrine

Tags: search, doctrine, symfony

I'm a total beginner with Symfony2 and I have a problem using Doctrine right.
I habe created an entity for an existing database and I can use Doctrine to search within the database using the findById, findByAuthor etc. functions.
My next step was to create a HTML form where the user can enter several arguments.
My goal is, that Doctrine now searches the database for all entities, who match all/at least one of the arguments.
I hoped that I can do this using an entity with the typed in data but I don't know how.

Hopefully you understand what I mean and can help me :)

Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do this using custom queries. This is done through [DQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) mostly.

As for making this seemless, you will need to create yourself a [custom repository](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories) class if not already done to put the query into. It seems like a bit of a overhead. I went through that phase of looking around for alternatives too. But in the end, it's quite simple.

When asking for the repository for the entity type, Doctrine will just provide you with an instance of your class and it will transparent.

Answer (score 0):

For simple conditions, you can use the `findBy` method. 
With `$em` the entity manager

```
$em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity')->findBy(array(
    'id' => $id, 
    'author' => $author));
```

More information [with the Doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

For more complicated conditions, you'll have to use [DQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-dql)