# Custom search using doctrine and symfony2

Tags: search, symfony, doctrine

I want to create a searchController, that searches the db for whatever keywords the user enters into a textbox. I have looked at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033474/search-for-several-arguments-with-doctrine) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528435/database-searching-using-doctrine-and-symfony2) and many more.

This is what I have so far:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request) {
        if ($request->getMEthod() == 'GET') {
            $title = $request->get('Search_term');
            //echo "<div class=\"searchText\">Search Results</div><hr/>";
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $Search_terms = explode(' ', $title); //splits search terms at spaces
            $query = "SELECT * FROM Entity/Adverts WHERE ";

            foreach ($Search_terms as $each) {
                // echo $each."<br/>";
                $i = 0;
                $i++;
                if ($i == 1)
                    $query .= "Adv_title LIKE '%$each%' ";
                else
                    $query .= "OR Adv_title LIKE '%$each%' ";
            }
            $query = $em->createQuery($query);
            $numRow = $query->count();
            if ($numRow > 0) {
                while ($query->fetch()) {
                    $repository = $em->getRepository('YCRYcrBundle:Adverts')->findBy(array(
                        'advTitle' => $title
                    ));

                    /*    echo "<h2><a href='#'> $title</a> </h2>";
                      echo "$desc <br /> <br />";
                      echo"<a href='/201308/View/YCR/index.php' class='link-button right'><span>Apply</span></a>"; */
                }
            }
            /* else
              echo "none found for \"<b>$SearchTerm </b>\"</br>Check spelling"; */
        }
        return $this->render('YCRYcrBundle:Search:search.html.twig', array('title' => $title->getAdvTitle()));
}
```

What is missing from this code to make it work, and or what is wrong?

**Edit:**

sorry of I was unclear. I am getting the following error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Query::count() in C:\wamp\www\201308\src\YCR\YcrBundle\Controller\SearchController.php line 28
>   and do not know what is wrong as I am new to Symfony and doctrine.

This is what I have in my search.html.twig:

```
{% extends "YCRYcrBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>YCR Job Search</title>

        <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="stylesheets/colour.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        </head>
        <body onload="b = setInterval('clear()', 0);">


            <div class="topDiv">
                <div style="float: left;">
                    <img src="/201308/View/images/ycr.jpg" alt="ycr"></div>
                <br/>

                <!--<H2>Search for a Job</H2>--> 
                <div class="searchform">
    <form id="formsearch" name="p" method="get" action="index.php">
          <span>

          <input name="Search_term" class="editbox_search" id="editbox_search"          maxlength="80" value="<?php $this; ?>" type="text" />
          </span>
              <input type="image" name="button_search" src="images/search.gif"     class="button_search" alt="" />
        </form>
                <br/>          
                <div id="search_results">

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- </div>-->

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-    1.7.2.min.js"></script><!--javascript jquery library-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../View/scripts/Script.js"></script>         


{% endblock %}
```

When the user searches, for example programmer, to display like this:

```
-Programmer

-a summary of the description of what a programmer entails

-a button/link that reads: read more, that takes me to a page with full description
```

Comment: What is happening when it's "not working"?

Comment: you are getting `$title` and sending it back. your results are in `$repository` so i think `$repository` is what you should send back in the `render` state

Comment: sorry if I was unclear about "not working", I get the following error:
> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Query::count() in C:\wamp\www\201308\src\YCR\YcrBundle\Controller\SearchController.php line 28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty far off the mark.  Query has no count function, that's a querybuilder function.  You may write raw sql, but you are better served learning querybuilder : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html.  Remember, doctrine is designed to give you a list of entities, that you pass to the twig to do stuff with.

Also, your twig won't do much, see the basics of usage in the very crude twig I've included.  use `{{entity.method}}` or `{{entity.field}}` to get the various display properties of each entity.  Use a twig foreach to loop through them all.  Take a look at my example in your context, and then go read the twig documents to fill in the gaps.  http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation

The Controller

```
public function searchAction(Request $request) {
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'GET') {
        $title = $request->get('Search_term');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $qb = $em->getRepository('YCRYcrBundle:Adverts')
                  ->createQueryBuilder('a');
        $searches= explode(' ', $title);

        foreach ($searches as $sk => $sv) {
            $cqb[]=$qb->expr()->like("CONCAT($sv, '')", "'%$sv%'");
        }

        $qb->andWhere(call_user_func_array(array($qb->expr(),"orx"),$cqb));

        $adverts = $qb->getResult();
    }
    return $this->render('YCRYcrBundle:Search:search.html.twig'
                        , array('adverts' => $adverts));
}
```

And a twig file

```
{# Your other stuff #}
{% for advert in adverts %}
    {{advert.getId}}
    {# call the various method and fields for your display#}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm sure it wouldn't.  Thanks for noting the typo.

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute the query (with execute ) or you wont get an array. and you should be using the query builder instead DQL string concatenation. Read the doctrine doc on basic doctrine usage , the entity namespace seems to be incorrect too.

i quote you  :

```
  $query = $em->createQuery($query);
            $numRow = $query->count();
```

should be at least :

```
  $query = $em->createQuery($query);
            $numRow = count($query->execute())
```

edit : not sure wether you would be getting an array or an ArrayCollection , check if the count fonction works on the ArrayCollection.

Comment: I tried it, but I don't think my mysql syntax is correct, because it gives me the following error:                                        _"[Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got '*'"_ I think it doesn't recognize the `Select *`.

Comment: solved that problem by replacing it with `SELECT a FROM YCRYcrBundle:Adverts WHERE` but now it tells me that my syntax is wrong near my wildcard `%`: _[Syntax Error] line 0, col 59: Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got '%'._ What do you ibn DQL for a wildcard?